# What is smallest way to split object into array of object based on key/value pairs in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've got this object:

```
var obj = {
    family : [{name: 'will', age: 30}, {name: 'husain', age: 12}],
    friends : [{name: 'cody', age: 31}, {name: 'jeff', age: 11}],
    school : [{name: 'daniel', age: 20}, {name: 'carl', age: 15}]
}
```

convert it into this

```
var obj = [
    {family : [{name: 'will', age: 30}, {name: 'husain', age: 12}]},
    {friends : [{name: 'cody', age: 31}, {name: 'jeff', age: 11}]},
    {school : [{name: 'daniel', age: 20}, {name: 'carl', age: 15}]}
];
```

Write now I am using `for..in` to build a new array and create object with key as key for new object and so on.

I'm doing this right now

```
var arr = [];

for (let key in obj) {
    arr.push({key: obj[key]})
}
```

Comment: Without seeing the code you have it's hard to say much. Does your code work? Do you have some performance problems?

Comment: it works, but it takes a lot of space, and can't help but feel it'd could be simpler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) is your best option:

```js
var obj = {
    family : [{name: 'will', age: 30}, {name: 'husain', age: 12}],
    friends : [{name: 'cody', age: 31}, {name: 'jeff', age: 11}],
    school : [{name: 'daniel', age: 20}, {name: 'carl', age: 15}]
}
var r = Object.keys(obj).map(x => ({[x]: obj[x]}) )

console.log(r)
```